# Need Help Using A Radio Module (Gain Value)

Tags: rf, radio, lora

I'm using the RFM98PW-443S2 RF module for a project. Microcontrollers I will be using this module with separately are: STM32F446RET6 and ATmega2560.

Datasheet link: https://www.hoperf.com/data/upload/portal/20190301/RFM98PW.pdf

I tested the module and got a 3.2km range while I need a 6-8km range.

I'm using this module with this library on Arduino: https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib
I'm using the SX1278.h library from here.

Further investigating this library I found out that this library limits the output power to 17dBm since well this was designed for SX1278 (Max output power: 20Dbm)

I ran a test where I compared the output power o RFM98PW with RFM98W (SX1278 without any external amplifier). I measured the RSSI value from the same distance (20cm) and got the same result from both modules. So the 98PW output is the same as 98W because of the library.

I asked the dev for help here: https://github.com/jgromes/RadioLib/discussions/308

They told me to find out the gain value of the amplifier inside the RFM98PW module.

Then I would be able to tweak the output power of the SX1278 inside the module to get it amplified to 30dBm.
The dev said if I set the output too high the amplifier wouldn't work properly.

I mailed HopeRF but got no response.

**I need help using this module or learning the gain of the amplifier inside the module.**

PS: Yes I checked the datasheet and couldn't find anything there either.

Comment: test the range using the slowest bit rate available

Comment: Which band are you aiming for that allows 30dBm for what country? Start there.

Comment: @Lundin no worries about legal limits in this project. This RF module will be used in a deserted area in a rocketry competition. 433MHz band in Turkey tho.

Comment: @Exclose The authorities in Turkey specifically are pedantic with radio compliance. I don't remember what power limit they have for SRD on 433MHz, but it is unlikely that much larger than the limits used in EU. I very much doubt they allow 30dBm, you need to check this first thing you do.

Comment: I poked around, wasn't easy to find the relevant documents for 433MHz in Turkey since there's no English version. [This is what applies for license-free use (see 14a)](https://www.btk.gov.tr/uploads/regulations/frekans-tahsisinden-muaf-telsiz-cihaz-sistemleri-olcutler.pdf). And just as I suspected they are using _exactly the same requirements_ as the European Union. 10mW ERP with < 10% duty cycle and compliance to EN 300 220. 

LoRA has no problem with the duty cycle requirement, but you are not allowed to send 30dBM on this band! That's 100 times more than the 10mW ERP limit and illegal.

Comment: @Lundin I got the amateur radio license though. I think it allows me to use this module. And as I said this will be in a deserted area quite far away from any city.

Comment: No, this is a SRD. License-free also doesn't mean "anything goes", the radio must conform to EN/ETSI 300 220 where you have various requirements on occupied bandwidth, out-of-band emissions, spurious emissions, harmonics and so on. All which will get amplified 100 times higher as well.